# Can I code the Bluetooth of my Android device and set a condition in a specific range?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am making an app to alarm the users if their phone is being stolen. I will use an Android phone and an arduino Bluetooth device to be the point of reference ..

My problem is.. is it possible that to set a specific range to the android Bluetooth  to trigger the alarm of the phone??

Because my plan is if distance between the arduino and the Android phone reaches 3 meters both the device will alarm..

Pls. I need your help..

Answer (score 0):

One of the most obvious ways you can do this keep the socket connection open until it disconnects. Bluetooth range is approximately 32feet (10m) for most devices upon which the device will be disconnected. Upon disconnection the user can be notified (on the connection being lost/ bike stolen?).

Android's low energy bluetooth might be a solution if you want to conserve battery life, otherwise the normal version is fine.

If you want to get really fancy you can use geocoding(using longitude and latitude of both where your phone is and where the bike is) if the distance exceeds a certain distance( more realistically a couple of 100 meters) a notification can be sent to the phone about a possible bike theft situation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use BLE GATT server and send heart bit to client when heart bit not deliver client is not in Bluetooth range  . you cant find distance between two Bluetooth device